# Error in Using Cropperjs in AngularCli project

Tags: javascript, angular, cropperjs

I user croperjs for my AngularCli Project for image croping. but there are some errors.. I try it several times but it still there what do i do to fixed it?

errors are:

> error TS2339: Property 'files' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'.
>
> error TS2339: Property 'result' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'.
>
> error TS2339: Property 'result' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'.
>   error TS2540: Cannot assign to 'cropper' because it is a constant or a read-only property.
>
> error TS2339: Property 'files' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'.
>
> error TS2339: Property 'getCroppedCanvas' does not exist on type '""'.
>
> error TS2339: Property 'value' does not exist on type 'Element'.
>
> error TS2339: Property 'src' does not exist on type 'Element'.
>
> error TS2339: Property 'download' does not exist on type 'Element'.

**my html file is:**

```
<body>
<main class="page">
    <h2>Upload,Crop and save.</h2>
    <!-- input file -->
    <div class="box">
        <input type="file" id="file-input">
    </div>
    <!-- leftbox -->
    <div class="box-2">
        <div class="result"></div>
    </div>
    <!--rightbox-->
    <div class="box-2 img-result hide">
        <!-- result of crop -->
        <img class="cropped" src="" alt="">
    </div>
    <!-- input file -->
    <div class="box">
        <div class="options hide">
            <label> Width</label>
            <input type="number" class="img-w" value="300" min="100" max="1200" />
        </div>
        <!-- save btn -->
        <button class="btn save hide">Save</button>
        <!-- download btn -->
        <a href="" class="btn download hide">Download</a>
    </div>
</main>
</body>
```

**my ts file is:**

```
declare var Cropper: any;
....code here...
export class SixComponent implements OnInit {
rec = {}
handlesSize: any;
currentHandle: false;
drag: false;


//@ViewChild('layout1') canvas;
constructor() { }

ngOnInit() {

const result = document.querySelector('.result'),
  img_result = document.querySelector('.img-result'),
  img_w = document.querySelector('.img-w'),
  img_h = document.querySelector('.img-h'),
  options = document.querySelector('.options'),
  save = document.querySelector('.save'),
  cropped = document.querySelector('.cropped'),
  dwn = document.querySelector('.download'),
  upload = document.querySelector('#file-input'),
  cropper = '';

// on change show image with crop options
upload.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
  debugger;
  if (e.target.files.length) {
    // start file reader
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = (e) => {
      if (e.target.result) {
        // create new image
        let img = document.createElement('img');
        img.id = 'image';
        img.src = e.target.result
        // clean result before
        result.innerHTML = '';
        // append new image
        result.appendChild(img);
        // show save btn and options
        save.classList.remove('hide');
        options.classList.remove('hide');
        // init cropper
        cropper = new Cropper(img);
      }
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);
  }
});

// save on click
save.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  // get result to data uri
  let imgSrc = cropper.getCroppedCanvas({
    width: img_w.value // input value
  }).toDataURL();
  // remove hide class of img
  cropped.classList.remove('hide');
  img_result.classList.remove('hide');
  // show image cropped
  cropped.src = imgSrc;
  dwn.classList.remove('hide');
  dwn.download = 'imagename.png';
  dwn.setAttribute('href', imgSrc);
});

}
}
```

Thank you

Comment: you basically hacked your way through the component to avoid the of use typescript, ignored Angular way of doing things, went straight to the DOM and manipulated it by hand. why bother with Angular at all ?

Comment: Based on your angular version, you can use `Renderer` or `Renderer2` to manipulate the DOM